# Finding indices and substrings of strings in Zsh?

Tags: shell-script, shell, zsh

I'm making functions in my zshrc file to help me navigate to certain frequently visited webpages. For instance, calling `61b` would open https://sp21.datastructur.es/, `61b lab6` would open https://sp21.datastructur.es/materials/lab/lab6/lab6, and `61b proj2` would open https://sp21.datastructur.es/materials/proj/proj2/proj2. I need to somehow create a substring of `lab6` or `proj2` so that I can use `lab` or `proj` in the URL.

```
function 61b() {
  if [ -n "$1" ]; then
    open https://sp21.datastructur.es/materials/??/$1/$1
  else
    open https://sp21.datastructur.es/
  fi
}
```

What would I put in the **??**. I've tried just about everything.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform many string operations by using more elaborate forms of [parameter expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion) of the form `${stuffPARAM}` or `${PARAMstuff}` (or combinations of them).

For example, `${1%%[0-9]##}` is the first parameter (`$1`) with the digits ([wildcard pattern](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Operators) `[0-9]##`) removed at the end (`${…%%…}`). You need to have `setopt extended_glob` in order for the wildcard pattern `[0-9]##` to work; put that in your `.zshrc` or in the function:

```
function 61b() {
  setopt local_options extended_glob unset
  if [ -n "$1" ]; then
    open https://sp21.datastructur.es/materials/${1%%[0-9]##}/$1/$1
  else
    open https://sp21.datastructur.es/
  fi
}
```

Instead of `[0-9]##`, you can use `<->`, which stands for a number in any range. (“Number” meaning a non-negative integer written in decimal, so it's equivalent to a sequence of digits.)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I doubt that `https://sp21.datastructur.es/materials///` isn't useful, so I think thatreating empty as unset is the most useful behavior, in addition to being the simplest behavior to explain (since the asker already understands it).

Comment: Ah, yes, I inverted the option, thanks.

Comment: Or make it: `61b() open https://sp21.datastructur.es/${1:+materials/${1%%<->}/$1/$1}`